# How to save a file in database using AngularJS and Rest Framework?

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm new to AngularJS and I would like to *save a file to my database* but it doesn't work with the `<input type="file" ng-model="" >`
and then save it using `$http.post` in the controller . 
Does anyone know a simple way to upload a file from a form and save it to database ?

thank you

Comment: Did you end up solving this? If so, what solution did you use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are posting a file, you have multipart form data. This is a solved issue in angular though, look at [ng-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi @Garrett Wills , please do you have ana example with java REST API in the backend ?